# valgrind mips doesn't show stack trace

Tags: c, mips, valgrind

I'm using valgrind 3.13 on mips platform, however I write a test program and found valgrind didn't trace to file line number, for x86 it works fine. what could be the problem?

```
# valgrind --trace-children=yes --leak-check=yes --num-callers=20 /tmp/a.out

==2957== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==2957== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==2957== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==2957== Command: /tmp/a.out
==2957==
==2957== Invalid write of size 4
==2957==    at 0x4000B90: ??? (in /lib/ld-uClibc.so.0)
==2957==    by 0x4000B3C: ??? (in /lib/ld-uClibc.so.0)
==2957==  Address 0x7e8bdcbc is on thread 1's stack
==2957==  4 bytes below stack pointer
==2957==
==2957== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==2957==    at 0x48B4A44: ??? (in /lib/libc.so.0)
==2957==    by 0x48ADBE4: ??? (in /lib/libc.so.0)
==2957==
buf=test buf

in func1:x[10]=10
/tmp/a.out: can't resolve symbol '__libc_freeres'
==2957==
==2957== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2957==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2957==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==2957==
==2957== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==2957==
==2957== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==2957== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==2957== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Below is my test.c, compiled with mips toolchain with option "-g -O0"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

func1()
{
    int *x=malloc(10*sizeof(int *));
    x[10]=10;
    printf("in func1:x[10]=%d\n", x[10]);
}

main()
{
    char buf[2];
    char buf2[10];

    strcpy(buf,"test buf\n");
    printf("buf=%s\n", buf);
    func1();
}
```

Comment: Did you compile and link with the `-g` option?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, he said that *compiled with mips toolchain with option "-g -O0"*.

Comment: @ks1322 : but the OP didn’t say whether he linked with `-g` or show the compilation command line demonstrating that it was all done at once.

Comment: Do you compile with `-fomit-frame-pointer`? See Valgrind faq: http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/faq.html#faq.unhelpful.

Comment: Here's my compile cmd:
mips-linux-gcc -g -O0 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-stack-check test.c

Some new discovery, after I compile use -fstack-check, then valgrind will report line number, but the number is incorrect:
==1912== Invalid write of size 4
==1912==    at 0x4007E0: main (test.c:13)
==1912==  Address 0x7ebffbbc is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd